# Integral/infinite sum related to Bessels which pop up in optical coherence theory

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

In propagating partially coherent optical fields, the following integral pops up:

$$I_1=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos[\theta]+b\cos^2[\theta])}d\theta,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. If we consider reducing the power on the cosine we find a related integral:

$$I_2=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos[\theta]+b\cos[2\theta])}d\theta.$$

If we use the Jacobi-Anger expansion we can instead consider an infinite sum:

$$I_2=2\pi\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}i^{-m}J_{2m}(a)J_m(b)$$

However, in either case I have been unable to find a closed form solution for $I_2$. It would be very helpful to find a closed form solution in order to reduce computation time. Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Recently I got interested in exploring a generalization of this; namely, generalizing the exponent to an arbitrary Fourier (cosine) series rather than just the first two harmonics. In doing so I stumbled across the following [paper](http://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/view/376/0) which considers such integrals in the context of so-called 'multivariable Bessel functions.' I'm not sure whether it'll be useful for your purposes, but I thought I'd pass it along.

Comment: @Semiclassical The paper appears to be intimately related and is an important resource to the study of this problem. As a side note, $I_1$ is an approximation and in general the exponent contains an infinite series.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting thing about $I_1$ is that it satisfies a PDE. Specifically, it satisfies a version of Schroedinger's equation:: $$\partial_a^2 I_1 =-\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta\;e^{i a\cos[\theta]+i b\cos^2[\theta])}d\theta=i\partial_b I_1.$$ Similar remarks apply to $I_2$. Since the $a=0$ and $b=0$ cases are both reducible to a zeroth-order Bessel function, this suggests that an attack along PDE lines (e.g. separation of variables, method of characteristics) may be more fruitful than direct integration.

Comment: Your answer is quite interesting. How would I go about solving the equation?

Comment: I'll be honest, I posted that answer mostly in the hope that someone else could make use of the insight. But I do know a few things to attempt, so I'll try to update my answer eventually.

Comment: An explicit formula is certainly out of question here but we can discuss the ways to compute it quickly with decent accuracy though in that case more information is needed (range of arguments, precision, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the modified generalized Bessel functions introduced in [1] and [2],

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta\; e^{i(a \cos\theta \,+\, b \cos 2\theta)} = 2\pi \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty i^{-m} J_{2m}(a)\,J_m(b) = 2\pi J_0(a,b;-i) = 2\pi I_0(a,-ib)
$$

In [1], [2], and other publications of the authors, they discuss the numerical evaluation of these functions, as well as many examples of their usefulness in quantum mechanics.

[1] G Dattoli et al, [Theory of generalized Bessel functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02726105)

[2] G Dattoli et al, [Theory of generalized Bessel functions II](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02723125)

Comment: What is the formula for the multivariable Bessel function in that paper? It is not free unfortunately.

Comment: The paper [Generalized Bessel Functions of the Anger Type and Applications to Physical Problems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X84711942) by the same authors is available. Here the generalized Bessel functions are related to generalized Anger functions, which are then evaluated numerically.